# Pretty-printing Wordpress HTML output for development purposes

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pretty-print

Is there a simple way (plugin / function) that uses Tidy or some other lib to pretty-print Wordpress's HTML output?

It's unreadable as it is and it's almost impossible to write a theme with proper indentation with all the includes / hooks going on all over the place.

Performance is not an issue as this only needs to be active for development purposes.

Comment: Well, firebug does provide you with indentation in it's html tab.

Comment: This is better suited to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that firebug's HTML view is dynamic - i.e. it will update according to any DOM manipulation. Depending on your requirements, and whether your page has any scripts present, this may be an issue.

Comment: If you need it static I suppose he could just copy n' paste the source from 'view source' over to an IDE and have that format the code for him.

Comment: I sometimes use this technique but that involves copy-pasting the code, creating a new document to paste it into, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly indent PHP/HTML mixed code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155799/how-to-properly-indent-php-html-mixed-code)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

1. Get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. Use PHP [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
3. Include whitespace in your output using `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), etc.

Comment: I do have Firebug. Problem is not with stuff from variables but more of the way things from core Wordpress get included (eg. get_header(), get_footer()).

Answer (score 0):

Give [Kint PHP Debugger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kint-debugger/) a try.

Works great for doing var_dumps with a nice UI.

Example:

```
$items = array('pine', 'apple', array('numbers' => [1,2,3,4]));
d($items);
```