# Joomla New Component Install Error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

When I install new Joomla and my component are in Joomla 2.5x and I am updating Joomla 3x version but in front-side I get an error:

> Ex:syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour Can you provide more information? Can you, for example,  identify and post the file which triggers the syntax error?

Comment: you'll find the error in the apache error log most likely, once you identify the extension responsible check the owner's website and update it (manually or restore a backup)

Comment: I also suggest you send the exact error, So that you will get the exact fix for that issue . Check with the below link, might be you will get the answer for your issue https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

Comment: Still you did not post the exact error, Con google chrome console, you can find the file name and the some more details on that issue. Please post that one.

Answer (score 0):

As i have investigated with that above error you have posted, they might be a two reason for that, either the component not install correct or In the code you have missed the curly prases at the end of the php file.

So there is two steps which overcome this problem,

```
    1) Reinstall the component which solve this issue.
    2) Find the exact file and found that might be syntactically not correct (i.e, <?php} {?> and <? ). 
    Please avoid <? and use <?php and keep spaces at curly braces (i.e, <? } ?> instead of <?php } ?>
go to php.ini then find short_open_tag= Off set to short_open_tag= On
```

If you want further more, please check this links [ComponentReinstall](https://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/153-professional-member-support/222304-solved-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in-com-comprofiler-plugin-language-default-language-default-language-php)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953362/how-to-fix-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-error-in-php)

Thanks & Regards,
Kaif