# PhpStorm: How to separate PHP & HTML indentation

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, indentation

Is it possible to configure PhpStorm 8 to indent HTML and PHP code separately?

I'll copy the examples from this question: [How to properly indent PHP/HTML mixed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155799/how-to-properly-indent-php-html-mixed-code)

How PhpStorm formats the code currently:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <?php if ($row->foo()): ?>
        <?php echo $row ?>
      <?php else: ?>
        Something else
      <?php endif ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

How I want it to look like:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
  <tr>
  <?php if ($row->foo()): ?>
    <?php echo $row ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    Something else
  <?php endif ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not currently possible. See [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17786#comment=27-811782)